# Laravel docker cron nginx 502 bad gateway issue

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, dockerfile

**I have been trying to setup Laravel with docker.**
My folder structure is show below.
When I tried to access http://127.0.0.1:8001/ to run laravel app
it give me **502 Bad Gateway** nginx/1.24.0
Could anyone give me any solution on this?

[image]

[image]

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    server:
        image: "nginx:stable-alpine"
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0.25
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: smc
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        expose:
            - "3307"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8002:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        logging:
            driver: "none" # disable saving logs
        ports:
            - 1025:1025 # smtp server
            - 8003:8025 # web ui
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Linux Library
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev 

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# PHP Extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext intl pdo_mysql gd

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the web container log to see if the php-fpm service actually started

Comment: In your php-fpm container Dockerfile, don't forget to add `EXPOSE 9000`. You can also expose the port in your `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Can I give advice? It's not to resolve the problem, but *after* you've resolved the problem. 1) php-fpm Dockerfile, FROM: not PHP 8.1.0, but just PHP 8.1, it will give you latest stable PHP 8.1 version. 2) MySQL, also add username/password for MySQL, not just root password. 3) nginx `nginx.conf` becomes 'default.conf' in the container. Actually, nginx *also* has a config file called `nginx.conf`, not to configure the site, but general configs